# Constant of integration with double stroke like in Mathematica

Tags: fonts, typography

I would like to know if there is a package that allows text to print like the following output from Wolfram Mathematica.

So basically the `c_1` and `c_2` that appears below. What is the best approach for this?

[image: Style that I want]

Comment: Which approach is "best" for you strongly depends on which math fonts are available on your system. For instance, is the Mathematica font for LaTeX installed? One way to find out is to compile the following test document: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[bb=mma]{mathalpha} \begin{document} $\mathbb{c}_1+\mathtt{t}\mathbb{c}_2$ \end{document}`. Give it a try. (I trust you've figured out that `mma` is shorthand for Mathematica.)

Comment: @Mico I have mathalpha installed in MiKTeX Console but I get `Font U/mmambb/m/n/10=mmambb at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> `

Comment: With all respect due to the people at Wolfram, their usage of doubly stroked symbols is terribly awful.

Comment: @egreg I mean I just wanted to have a way to distinguish constants from functions, and since I've been using Mathematica I thought I'd look for ways to replicate what they have done

Comment: There is even the [`bbold` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/bbold)

Comment: Doing a search for "blackboard board" fonts on CTAN give the following [results](https://ctan.org/topic/font-bbd)

Comment: Also of note: ISO style is for variables to be slanted, and to distinguish constants by making them upright.

Comment: @Davislor although I'm not aware of any ISO standard for mathematical documents, just ISO/IEC 80000-2 which standardises the slightly eccentric usages of mathematical formulae in engineering (or "natural sciences and technology" as it refers to it)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, maybe that’s what the OP wants. :)